# Route with param returns "template not found" but exists

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route set up which is working as far it it gets the parameter value, gets data from a json file.

The page exists however, if I try and return the view with the data so I can display it in the page, it just returns "Error: template not found: /projects/work/index.html"

How do I render the view?

```
router.get('/projects/work/index/:id', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.params.id); //Returns an ID ok

  var id = req.params.id;
  var obj = require('./projectdata.json');

  console.log(obj.items.filter(function (value) {return value.id === id;})[0].title); //Returns data ok
  var record = obj.items.filter(function (value) {return value.id === id;})[0];

  res.render('/projects/work/index', record);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did set up the templates location. Standard is to set it to 'views', but you can set it to anything:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Make sure to set up the view engine (for example ejs, jade or handlebars...)

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

After these, you should be able to render the views:

```
response.render("index", {record});
```

Comment: The template does exist and other pages are displayed, i'm using nunjucks and it's only when the request has an parameter defined that it errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I dropped the / off the path to the file.

```
res.render('projects/work/index', {record});
```